# zoom in R - plotly using the dynamicTicks

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

How could I set the `ggplotly(dynamicTicks = TRUE)` just for y axis ?! 
In the following, by zooming in, both `x` and `y` axis ticks will change :

```
ggiris <- qplot(Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
ggplotly(ggiris,dynamicTicks = TRUE)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
ggplotly(ggiris, dynamicTicks = "y")
```

My R/libraries versions:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
plotly_4.9.2.1      
ggplot2_3.3.0
```